# Why does conversion of non-bootable hfs+ external drive to apfs fail (on macOS Mojave)? com.apple.DiskManagement error -69888

Tags: mojave, filesystem, apfs, file-conversion, hfs+

The attempted conversion is failing. Does anyone know why?

`Disk Utility.app` error:

```
Converting “mySSD” to APFS

Converting HFS Volume to an APFS Container which will export one APFS Volume
The target is the Journaled HFS+ volume “mySSD” on disk3 backed via CoreStorage on disk2s2
The target is a data disk; it is not a macOS system disk
Found APFS EFI driver /usr/standalone/i386/apfs.efi to install into the APFS Container
Saving encryption context
The target is encrypted
Unmounting disk3
Exiting conversion operations with error code -69888
The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.DiskManagement error -69888.)

Operation failed…
```

Environment and disk details:

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.14.6
BuildVersion:   18G84
$ diskutil list
[...]
/dev/disk3 (external, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS mySSD                  +499.1 GB   disk3
                                 Logical Volume on disk2s2
                                 BCFD2F21-6361-4256-AF3A-ACB4D78D7669
                                 Unlocked Encrypted

$
```

Comment: google.com searching for `com.apple.DiskManagement error -69888` thus far produces nothing useful.  :-/